# Strange residue on cell with Data Validation when using Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

Thanks to [Raystafarian](https://superuser.com/users/116196/raystafarian) I get rid of that left over Data Validation residue box by deleting all of them from the work book before exiting.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Delete all drop down lists
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each shp In ws.Shapes
            If shp.Name Like "Drop Down *" Then
                shp.Delete
            End If
        Next shp
    Next ws

    Sheet1.Activate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

=================

## Original question

I'm running into an annoying bug with Excel VBA. See this screenshot.
I use an Excel worksheet as a User Input form.
On the form I have several places where I put Data Validation.
After the user hit Enter I use this bit of code to clear the form.

```
For Each a In Sheets("frmBienNhan").Range("C5:K31")
    If a.Locked = False Then
        a.Value = ""
    End If
Next a
```

After the code ran several times these damn arrows appear. It is just like the Dropdown list of Data Validation but when you click on it the list is empty. I cannot select the cell behind it. I cannot remove it even if I use Clear all Validation or Clear All commands in Excel. This is not a big deal but it's annoying to the user because they have to move the cursor to that cell using keyboard, otherwise they cannot select the true Data Validation Dropdown List.

Any thoughts or experience on this bug are more than welcome.

[image: Screenshot of the residual validation arrows]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holy Cow! I was struggling with this yesterday! I couldn't find any information about it on the web.

[image]

[image]

My solution was to use the immediate window in VBE (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>) to see what's on the page, so I ran something like this in a module -

```
Sub test()
Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    Debug.Print shp.Name
Next
End Sub
```

It printed all the shapes on my page. Then I found the errant drop down in the immediate window. So I typed this into the immediate window -

```
 activesheet.shapes("Drop Down 8").delete
```

Just use the shape name of yours.

Answer (score 1):

Try seetting a.Value to `vbNullString` instead of "". In VBA, setting a string to "" allocates memory for a char[0] array, which contains string constants like a terminator. `vbNullString` returns a  pointer to null, so its truly empty.

https://movefirstblog.wordpress.com/2008/06/28/vbnullstring-empty-cells-in-excel-vba/

Comment: Agreed, vbNullString is truly empty. I'll see if the bug persists after changing "" to vbNullString. I ran into this bug with ClearContents command on Data Validation cells as well, that's why I switched to using "".

Answer (score 0):

This is what I put on my Worksheet_BeforeSave handler.  The concept is that the dropdowns are from validations and for some odd reason Excel can sometimes leave some of these around.

```
' Clear off lingering dropdowns
Dim aShape As Shape
Dim aWorksheet As Worksheet
For Each aWorksheet in Me.Sheets
  For Each aShape In aWorksheet.Shapes
    If aShape.Type = msoFormControl Then
      If aShape.FormControlType = xlDropDown Then
        aShape.Delete
      End If
    End If
  Next
Next
```