# Find and remove form control in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that I'd like to use on my tablet computer.  The Excel app doesn't open files with 'form control '

Unless this refers to simple drop boxes, I'm not aware of any form controls.

Is there a way to search them out so that I  can delete them? I have excel 2016

Comment: Check this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Delete-controls-on-a-worksheet-9ddcf8f5-75b8-4ad6-98cf-611da389bb58?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'd found that article, but my issue is that I'm not aware of any form controls on the sheet, so I need to get able to 'seek and destroy' them

Comment: If by "drop boxes" you mean drop down lists, then those are considered controls to Excel.

Comment: Yes I did mean drop down lists, however another spreadsheet that I've tested has these,  yet still opens fine?

Comment: [this might be of help](http://superuser.com/questions/1029768/strange-residue-on-cell-with-data-validation-when-using-excel-vba/1030024#1030024) but then again it might not