# What is this extra drop down in Excel, and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10, microsoft-excel-2016

In Excel, I have two adjacent cells with the same Data Validation applied.

When selected, the bottom one has the appropriate drop down widget to the right. Clicking on the widget works normally, giving the appropriate list of choices as defined elsewhere.

When *not* selected, the top one still shows a control widget, though clearly of a different style. When clicked, this deviant widget shows an empty list. If the cell itself is selected, the correct widget overlays the deviant widget and functions correctly.

**What causes the deviant widget, and how do I get rid of it?**

I am currently using Excel 2016, but I have seen the same thing happen in 2013. It's also not isolated to this particular part of the sheet. I have other places where Data Validation is in use, and this rogue widget shows up and behaves the same way. I have been unable to determine any pattern of usage that causes it.

There's a [thread on Microsoft's Community support forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-excel/phantom-drop-down-boxes-in-excel-2016/06b1f356-842d-4aa6-b452-52cad0618a86), but none of the suggestions are suitable. The reproduction cases and workarounds don't pan out. There's a snippet of VBA code that allegedly fixes it, but I can't use it because it would destroy other parts of my workbook. I need a surgical method to remove it, and persistent method to prevent it.

[image: Two Dropdown Boxes]

Comment: should we assume from your user icon that you are on a Mac?

Comment: @mcgyver5 Nope, but good on you for recognizing it. Most people don't. :) Added tag.

Comment: Using Office 2016 on Windows 10, I'm unable to reproduce problem.  Maybe if you posted the exact steps you used.

Comment: not an answer, but this guy has same problem: http://superuser.com/questions/1065430/phantom-dropdowns-appearing-in-excel-spreadsheet?rq=1

Comment: and other users reported it here:  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-excel/phantom-drop-down-boxes-in-excel-2016/06b1f356-842d-4aa6-b452-52cad0618a86

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1029768/strange-residue-on-cell-with-data-validation-when-using-excel-vba/1030024#1030024